# How can I make run-time textbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I have WPF database application. My database has 10 tables, but one of them has a different number of columns. I edit data with `TextBox`, so if I select a table with 10 columns I need to have 10 `TextBoxes`.

I think I know how to add a `TextBox`, but if I do it the textbox "destroys" my application. I need to repair it, change background color, color of text and margrin.
This is my code:

```
public void AddTb()
    {
        TextBox tb2 = new TextBox();
        tb2.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
        tb2.Width = 60;
        tb2.Height = 23;
        tb2.Margin = new Thickness(304, 50, 0, 0);
        this.Content = tb2;           
    }
```

Pictures:
[working](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YHGI4XweFW5KS5RtfOfh2J0nJ2Gp8J4r/view?usp=sharing)
[not working](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1T6Q0ztprlfOZbJ-HAzsDJ6qD7RTa-Rod/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. I'm not too sure about WPF, don't use it, however I believe the 'this.Content = ...' is replacing ALL the content in the form (or whatever). Perhaps there is a Controls.add() method instead?

Comment: You set the `Content` of `this` to the `TextBox` that you are creating. You probably want to add it to some existing `Panel` instead of doing this: `theNameOfThePanel.Children.Add(tb2);`

Comment: Ok, it's working. Now, how can I change background and foreground color?

Comment: Guess `tb2.Background = tb2.Foreground = Brushes.Gray;`? But this is not what you have asked, for any further questions, please open a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the `Content` of `this` to the `TextBox` that you are creating. You probably want to add it to some existing `Panel` instead of doing this:

```
theNameOfThePanel.Children.Add(tb2);
```